# How to grep the braces '{'?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to `grep` a Linux system (Deb) for flags in a capture the flag competition. The following does not return any results and we know there are hundreds for `flag{ }` instances of text in a directory.

```
grep -rnw 'Downloads/' -e  'flag{' | more
```

Why? How can we search for `flag{`? While below works fine.

```
grep -rnw 'Downloads/' -e  'flag' | more
```

Comment: escape the `{`.

Comment: Please define _does not work_.

Comment: How do you escape the { ?

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of something that you are expecting would match.

Answer (score 6):

With `grep -w`, you are asking `grep` to only return matches that are immediately preceded by or followed by a newline (at the very start or end of a line) or a non-word character (a word character is a letter, digit or underscore).

This means that the text `this is flag{a}` will not be matched by `grep -w 'flag{`', since the character following the `{` in the text is a word character.

Similarly, `this is theflag{` would not be matched by `grep -w 'flag{'`.

You may dispose of the `-w` option and instead use an explicit zero-width word boundary pattern, for example at the beginning, so that you may match `flag{a}` but not `theflag{`.  With GNU `grep`, this may be done using

```
grep -rn '\<flag{' Downloads
```

or

```
grep -rn '\bflag{' Downloads
```

The `\<` pattern matches a word boundary at the start of a word (and `\>` matches at the end), while `\b` matches at both start and end.  `\<` and `\>` were originally inherited from the `ex` and `vi` editors and are more portable than `\b`.

GNU `grep` does not support `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` (which work the same way as `\<` and `\>`) to match at the beginning or end of words, but BSD `grep` does. BSD `grep` does not support `\b`.

Comment: This worked!  grep -rn '\bflag{' Downloads\   Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Grep with `-e` (denoting an expression will follow) uses Basic Regex by default. From `man grep`, under "Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions" ([online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended)):

> Traditional  `egrep`  did  not  support  the  `{` meta-character, and
>   some egrep implementations    support `\{` instead, so portable scripts
>   should avoid `{` in `grep -E` patterns  and  should  use    `[{]` to match a
>   literal `{`.
>
> GNU  grep `-E`  attempts  to support traditional usage by assuming
>   that `{` is not special if it    would be the  start  of  an  invalid 
>   interval  specification.   For  example,  the  command    `grep -E '{1'`
>   searches for the two-character string `{1` instead of reporting a syntax
>   error in    the regular expression.  POSIX allows this behavior as an
>   extension,  but  portable  scripts    should avoid it.

So the most portable option would be:

```
grep -rnw -e 'flag[{]' 'Downloads/'  | more
```

Comment: There's no `grep` implementation where `grep  'foo{'`without `-E` will be a problem. Having options after non-option arguments would be a problem in most though. So `grep -rnw 'flag{' Downloads` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'flag{' | grep -F 'flag{'
    flag{

echo 'flag{' | grep 'flag{'
    flag{

echo 'flag{' | grep -E 'flag{'
    flag{
```